# Firebase functions - Loop promises timeout

Tags: typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to loop on an array of `ids` to store async `promises` :

```
const getTokens = [];

for (const uid of uids) {
    const promise = await admin.database()
        .ref(`/tokens`)
        .orderByChild('uid')
        .equalTo(uid)
        .once('child_added');

    getTokens.push(promise);
}

const results = await Promise.all(getTokens);
```

But I always get the following error on the first assignment to `promise` const :

> Function execution took 60002 ms, finished with status: 'timeout'.

I heard about a Firebase SDK issue that could be fixed with this workaround :

```
...
const promise = await admin.database()
    .ref(`/tokens`)
    .orderByChild('uid')
    .equalTo(uid)
    .once('child_added').then(() => { console.log('Promise added.' });
...
```

But in my case, I still got the same issue.

Comment: Please edit the question to show the entire, minimal function that has this problem.  The error message you're showing is not likely related to the lines of code you're showing.

Comment: Why are you using `await` when you are adding to array for `Promise.all`?